# How to get memory information when benchmarking?

Tags: r, profiling, benchmarking

I'd like to time how several regression models are computed using different libraries.
Till now I was using something like this:

```r
benchmark(
 "mod1" = {mod1 <- glm(varOUT~var1+var2+var3+varfact+City, data=myDF, family = "binomial")},
 "mod2" = {mod2 <- glmer(varOUT~var1+var2+var3+varfact+(1|City/ID),data=myDF,family = "binomial")},
 "mod3" = {mod3 <- glmmTMB(varOUT~var1+var2+var3+varfact+(1|ID),data=myDF,family = "binomial")},
 replications=1
)
```

But now I would also like to add information about how much memory (maximum) is used by each of these regressions.  How can I do it?

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the package `bench`. Since you did not provide data I'll simply use an example from the vignette:

```
library(bench)

set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(x = runif(10000, 1, 1000), y=runif(10000, 1, 1000))

bnch <- bench::mark(
  logical = dat[dat$x > 500, ],
  which = dat[which(dat$x > 500), ],
  subset =subset(dat, x > 500),
  iterations = 150,
  check = FALSE
)

bnch
# A tibble: 3 x 14
  expression   min  mean median      max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc n_itr total_time result memory time 
  <chr>      <bch> <bch> <bch:> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <dbl> <int>   <bch:tm> <list> <list> <lis>
1 logical    392us 532us  505us    1.2ms     1878.     377KB     2   148     78.8ms <data~ <Rpro~ <bch~
2 which      308us 358us  331us 636.45us     2793.     260KB     1   149     53.4ms <data~ <Rpro~ <bch~
3 subset     470us 553us  538us   1.19ms     1808.     494KB     3   147     81.3ms <data~ <Rpro~ <bch~
# ... with 1 more variable: gc <list>
```

`mem_alloc` is what you are looking for, I think. The default is to check if all results are the same. Since there might be some differences between results in your case I set this to `check = FALSE`.

Comment: Maybe it won't work for me because the docs say:

`bench::mark()`  will throw an error if the results are not equivalent, so you don’t accidentally benchmark inequivalent code.


I've tried microbenchmark before but because of its internal working method it produced out of memory errors when benchmarking functions that need a lot of memory.

Maybe I can also use the package profmem, though I would prefer something integrated and simple.

Comment: I would still give it a try. With `check = FALSE` there will be no error if results are not equivalent.

Comment: Hello @JBGruber  I've been trying and it seems to work.  I've noticed the output of the mark() command apart from the timings contain very large objects (in my case whole regression models) on a tibble structure.  How can I just output the timing and memory?